# Heap corruption while freeing memory in a recursion function

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-corruption

I'm implementing an algorithm to select Kth smallest element of an array . so far when i was trying to free heap memory i got this error : crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer ...

```
int SEQUENTIAL_SELECT(int *S , int k , int n)
{
    if(n<=Q) // sort S and return the kth element directly
    {
        qsort(S,n,sizeof(int),compare);
        return S[k];
    }
    // subdivide S into n/Q subsequences of Q elements each
    int countSets = ceil((float)n/(float)Q);

    //sort each subsequnce and determine its median
    int *medians = new int[countSets];
    for(int i=0;i<countSets;i++)
    {
        if(i==countSets-1) 
        {
            int size = Q - (n%Q);
            qsort(&S[Q*i],size,sizeof(int),compare);
            medians[i] = S[i*Q+size/2];
            continue;
        }
        qsort(&S[Q*i],Q,sizeof(int),compare);
        medians[i] = S[i*Q+Q/2]; 
    }

    // call SEQUENTIAL_SELECT recursively to find median of medians 
    int m = SEQUENTIAL_SELECT(medians,countSets/2,countSets);
    delete[] medians;
    int size = (3*n)/4;

    int* s1 = new int[size]; // contains values less than m
    int* s3 = new int[size]; // contains values graten than m

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        s1[i] = INT_MAX;
        s3[i] = INT_MAX;
    }
    int i1=0;
    int i2=0;
    int i3=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(S[i]>m)
            s3[i3++] = S[i];
        else if(S[i]<m)
            s1[i1++] = S[i];
        else
            i2++; // count number of values equal to m
    }

    if( i1>=k )
        m = SEQUENTIAL_SELECT(s1,k,i1);
    else if( i1+i2+i3 >= k)
        m = SEQUENTIAL_SELECT(s3,k-i1-i2,i3);


    delete[] s3;
    delete[] s1;

    return m;
}
```

Comment: **WHERE** does the error occur exactly? Try running the application in `valgrind` or a similar memory debugger.

Comment: Why are you using `new int[]` instead of `std::vector<int>`? (Edit: the line `int size = Q - (n%Q);` looks incorrect to me.)

Comment: i want to use this function in a CUDA program and unfortunately you can't use std::vector in a CUDA kernel

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does this code have to do with CUDA?

Comment: valgrind is a Linux tools , I'm using vs2010

Comment: Nothing yet! after fix the bug , i add this function as an device functions to my CUDA application

Comment: OK so I have removed the CUDA tag. It isn't a CUDA programming question. Also pay a little attention to code formatting when you post here - no tabs, use spaces with an indentation level of 4.

Comment: In the last for loop you test the values of i1 and i2, but use i3 as an index. How is that working?

Comment: error rise after `delete[] s1;` executed in the last recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dcoder is certainly correct that `Q - n%q` is incorrect. It should be `n%Q`. In addition, the computation `size = (3*n)/4` is not reliable; try it with `n = 6` (assuming, as seems certain, that `Q` is actually 5) given the vector `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]`.

You could have avoided having a lot of eyes looking at your code by simply checking the values of the indexes at every array subscript assignment (although that wouldn't have caught the assignments inside of `qsort`, but more on that below).

It must surely have occurred to you that you are using an awful lot of memory to perform a simple operation, which could in fact be done in-place. Normally the reason to avoid doing an in-place operation would be that you need to preserve the original vector, but you're computing medians with `qsort` which sorts in-place, so the original vector is already modified. If that's acceptable, then there is no reason not to do the rest of the median-of-medians algorithm in-place. [1]

By the way, although I'm certainly not one of those who fears floating-point computations, there is no reason at all for `countSets = ceil(float(n)/float(Q))`. `(n + Q - 1)/Q` will work just fine. That idiom could usefully have been used in the computation of `size` as well, although I'm not at all sure where you got the `3n/4` computation from in the first place.

---

[Note 1] Hint: instead of grouping consecutively, divide the vector into five regions and find the median of the i<sup>th</sup> element of each region. Once you've found it, swap it with the i<sup>th</sup> element of the first region; once that is done, your first region -- the first fifth of the vector -- contains the medians and you can recurse on that subvector. That means actually writing out the median code as a series of comparisons, which is tedious but a lot faster than calling `qsort`. That also avoids the degenerate case I mentioned above, where the median-of-medians computation incorrectly returns the smallest element in the vector.